# Redis multiple key for value (multiplying search by keys)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, redis

I've just got stuck.
I have an issue when I working with an entity, I want to save it to Redis, but after some time **I want to get this entity, but I don't know what kind of query will be searched it.**

So, I need to save several keys into Redis. And I will be able to search my Entity by several queries.

For example,
I have an entity:

```
public class Book
{
  int Id,
  string Name
}
```

In one time, **I want to search this Entity by Id, in another case by Name.**

**Have you any propositions or solving how I can do it?**
**Maybe, I can use the tags** or something like that.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the answer. 
In Redis, you can use the Dictionary of the values.
So, following this issue, we have to save data by using Key & Value, where inside the Value we will have again Key & Value.

Then you will get Values by two keys.

As a result, you will have something like that

> **`HSET myhash field1 "Hello"`**

More information on official site (https://redis.io/commands/hset)

If we speak about performance, it means that we have time complexity: O(N) where N is the total number of elements in all given sets.

By following these rules:
O(n) time

```
1. Traversing an array
2. Traversing a linked list
3. Linear Search
4. Deletion of a specific element in a Linked List (Not sorted)
5. Comparing two strings
6. Checking for Palindrome
7. Counting/Bucket Sort and here too you can find a million more such examples.... In a nutshell, all Brute Force Algorithms, or Noob ones which require linearity, are based on O(n) time complexity
```

So, it means that the final access time to the element will be equal to about:
O(n) + O(m);

Answer (score 1):

Redis isn't like a regular table-based database server; you can't search arbitrarily. If you want to be able to search for something by id, then you need to *manually index by id* - presumably via a "hash" or similar that goes from the keyed value to the main item key (however you are storing the main items).

If you want *convenience* over this type of thing, maybe look at [RediSearch](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RediSearch) - an optional module for redis that simplifies this type of scenario while providing search options against nominated members. Your book objects would become "documents" in redisearch nomenclature.